# Best case Big O complexity

Tags: performance, algorithm, loops, big-o, time-complexity

The question:
***how can you limit the input data to achieve a better Big O complexity? Describe an algorithm for handling this limited data to find if there are any duplicates. What is the Big O complexity?***  (By limiting data, we mean size of data/ array).

Got the solutions i needed to help me achieve the task. I've removed my answers that i posted since they weren't necessary- thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand about "limiting input". Big-O/Omega/Theta complexity describes what happens to the running time of an algorithm *as the size of the input grows*. Limiting the input to some constant size effectively makes any algorithm O(1), though the constant may be *very* large :)

Comment: Highly recommend use code instead of the long description... even pseudo code.

Comment: @dlev could you by any chance describe the best algorithm that could be used to implement the use of the best case Big O complexity? One that i could work out easily is an algorithm with nested loops to implement the use an unsorted array with O(n^2) complexity... so could you possibly come up with a better algorithm with a better Big O than O(n^2) and also ensure that you are using an array of a specific size e.g. n=10,100, or 1000 etc. Thanks

Comment: @ALan I'm actually not that good at writing codes so i have written in the best way i could. The question also requires description of the algorithm so it's the best i could do. sorry if it's messy or isn't precise enough (or too-mouthful) :)

Comment: Well, you already described the simple sort 'n' scan algorithm, which you correctly point out is O(nlogn). Or, at least mostly correctly: it's O(complexity of the sort), which can actually be improved to O(n), if you use radix-sort, or another O(n) numeric sorting algorithm. Another approach is to keep adding the numbers to a hash table until either you're done or find a duplicate. This going to be O(n) in the expected case (though still O(n^2) if your input or hash function is disastrous). It also has the drawback of requiring O(n) additional space, which is :(

Comment: One final comment: you talk about "best case complexity", but again that's *usually* not that interesting. In the best case, even if you have 1 billion numbers to search, you compare the first two, find that they match, and you're done. Not all that interesting, though :)

Comment: @dlev thanks for the info. I'm really not concerned with the best case but it's come up in the exam therefore it's worth attempting now because usually when we think about Big O- we tend to look at, mainly, the worst case scenario but if asked the best case (unexpected), it'll be great to know beforehand. I'm gonna implement the sort 'n' scan algorithm and see what my tutor has to say. I'm guessing if i sort and compare the integers (array size of 10- used as my example), it'll be O(n) in the best case. oh and i meant O(1) if all the numbers are compared (sorry if the question isn't specific).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a better big O complexity if you know the max value your integer array can take. Lets say it as m.
The algorithm to do it is the variance of Bucket Sort. The complexity is O(n).
Source code of algorithm:

```
public boolean HasDuplicates(int [] arr, int m)
{

    boolean bucket[] = new boolean[m];

    for (int elem : arr)
    {

        if (bucket[elem])
        {
           return true; // a duplicate found
        }

        bucket[elem] = true;
    }   
    return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that sorting is our problem.

We know that sorting with only comparisons requires **Ω(n*log(n))** time and we can do it in `O(n*log(n))` by for example a merge sort.

However, if we limit `n` to some constant, for example let `n < 10^6`, then we can do it for any input in `O(10^6 * log(10^6))` which is `O(1)` in terms of `Big-O`.

The bottom line is, if you want to measure a performance in terms of the `Big-O` notation, you can not assume any size limitation on the input.

Comment: Actually what i did was change the algorithm to be based on a sorted array (by default) therefore the best/ worst case scenario would be O(n)... if we limit the data size to, let's say, 10 (10 integers in array), we would only need a single loop to iterate on each element a single time and within the loop we will be comparing the current integer to its successor (next integer in the array), if they match, then we could print using printf, else move back to the loop and iterate again until the end of array (n=10, therefore iterate n-1, n-2 and so on).. the worst case complexity would be O(n).

Comment: @user3418449 If you limit your input, let's say `n`, then from the theoretical point of view any correct algorithm will solve it `O(1)`